# Cannot assign "<class 'django.contrib.auth.models.User'>": "Model.user" must be a "User" instance

Tags: python, django, migration, django-migrations

Creating first entry to model is throwing error

I executed following commands to migrate

```
manage.py makemigrations
manage.py migrate
```

All worked fine, after I made those commands to create the first 'data' in the database

```
manage.py shell
from sms.models import Post
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
post_1 = Post(name="testname", email="testemail", gender="Monsieur", number="23233", author=User)
```

And it gave me this error:

```
ValueError: Cannot assign "<class 'django.contrib.auth.models.User'>": "Post.author" must be a "User" instance.
```

models.py files

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

THE_GENDER = [
    ("Monsieur", "Monsieur"),
    ("Madame", "Madame")
]


class Post(models.Model):


    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=THE_GENDER)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You see this error because you are trying to assing class object to `author` attribute. But it suppose to be User instance. So you should create user record first and use it, something like this instead:

```
user = User.objects.create_user(username="name", email="email@mail.com", password="Pass12345")
post_1 = Post(name="testname", email="testemail", gender="Monsieur", number="23233", author=user)
```

You can think about model class as about database table. While model instance represents record from this table.

Comment: Thanks you it worked and I  can see the Data in my Database, but now when I go on my webage app and add text on fied and press the submit button it gave me this error ```django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: sms_post.author_id
```

Comment: @tiberhockey welcome! As for your webpage you need to inject user before form saving, check this answer for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42482597/641249