# Setting the signed in user as field in Django model form

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a model form in my Django site, and I want it to automatically set the user who is signed in as the 'creator' (one of the fields), without allowing them to change it. This field doesn't need to show up in the form for the user, but it needs to be added to the database.

How would I go about this?

Here is the relevant forms.py form:

```
class EventForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields =  ('name','category','descr','start','end', 'location', 'attending', 'creator') 

        labels = {
            'name':  '',
            'category': '',
            'descr': '',
            'start': 'Start Date and Time',
            'end': 'End Date and Time',
            'location': 'Location',
            'attending': 'Attending',
            'creator': 'Creator',
        }

        widgets = { 'name':  forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Name of Event'}), 
        'category':  forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Event Category'}),
        'descr': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Description'}),
        'start':  forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'}), 
        'end': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'}),
        'location': forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-select', }),
        'attending': forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={'class':'form-control', }),
        'creator': forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-select', }),

        }
```

Here's the model (the User foreign key is from django.contrib.auth.models):

```
class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Event Name', max_length=300)
    category = models.CharField('Event Type',max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    descr = models.TextField(blank = True, null = True)
    start = models.DateTimeField('Start Time')
    end = models.DateTimeField('End Time', null= True, blank = True)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, blank = True, null = True, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    attending = models.ManyToManyField(People, blank=True)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, null = True, blank = True, on_delete = models.SET_NULL, related_name = 'event')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

And the view:

```
def add_event(response):
    sent = False
    if response.method == 'POST':
        form = EventForm(response.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            cd_instance = Countdown(name=form.cleaned_data['name'], time=form.cleaned_data['start'])
            cd_instance.save()
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/add-event?sent=True')

    else:
        form = EventForm()
        if 'sent' in response.GET:
            sent = True


        return render(response, 'main_app/add_event.html', {'form':form, 'sent': sent})
```

The view just has the form loaded with form = EventForm(), and the template displays form.as_p

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: add you models and views.py

Comment: article showing how here - (I suspect this site grabbed the content from elsewhere): https://www.programmersought.com/article/57142748536/ or this s/o reply: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42482597/4872140

Comment: perfect, thank you!